# the value of the property "if" is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, null

I am creating a quiz template that I will be using for module assessments. In the process I have created a True/False question with radio buttons. When I click on the score button to check my answer, I get The value of the property "if" is null or undefined, not a Function object." I checked the radio button id to make sure it matched the id in my If (document.getElementById('answer_true').checked) statement. All of my other multiple choice questions with radio buttons work fine. I just can't seem to put my finger on the source of the problem. The score button calls the check_tfQ function and tells me the problem is in the if statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// variable declarations
score=0;
counter=0;
c=1;
correct="Correct! ";
incorrect="Incorrect! ";
// function declarations for each question

function Question1()
{
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="1. Put question 1 here.";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="Put answer 1.1 here.";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="Put answer 1.2 here.";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="Put answer 1.3 here.";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Counter is "+c;
}
function checkQ1()
{
c+=1;
if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked)
{
score+=1;
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML=correct;
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML=score;
}
else if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked==false)
{
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML=incorrect;
}
}
function Question2()
{
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="2. Put question two here.";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="Put answer 2.1 here.";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="Put answer 2.2 here.";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="Put answer 2.3 here.";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Counter is "+c;
}
function checkQ2()
{
c+=1;
if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked)
{
score+=1;
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML=correct;
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML=score;
}
else if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked==false)
{
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML=incorrect;
}
}
function Question3()
{
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="3. Put question 3 here.";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="Put answer 3.1 here.";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="Put answer 3.2 here.";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="Put answer 3.3 here.";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Counter is "+c;
}
function checkQ3()
{
c+=1;
if (document.getElementById('answer_b').checked)
{
score+=1;
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML=correct;
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML=score;
}
else if (document.getElementById('answer_b').checked==false)
{
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML=incorrect;
}
}
function Question4()
{
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="4. Put question 4 here.";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="Put answer 4.1 here.";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="Put answer 4.2 here.";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="Put answer 4.3 here.";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Counter is "+c;
}
function checkQ4()
{
c+=1;
if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked)
{
score+=1;
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML=correct;
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML=score;
}
else if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked==false)
{
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML=incorrect;
}
}
function Question5()
{
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="5. Put question 5 here.";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="Put answer 5.1 here.";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="Put answer 5.2 here.";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="Put answer 5.3 here.";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Counter is "+c;
}
function checkQ5()
{
c+=1;
if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked)
{
score+=1;
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML=correct;
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML=score;
}
else if (document.getElementById('answer_a').checked==false)
{
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML=incorrect;
}
}
// function reveals fill in the blank question
function fitbQ()
{
document.getElementById("fitb_ques").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("answer_a").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("answer_b").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("answer_c").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Counter is "+c;
}
// function checks fill in the blank question
function check_fitbQ()
{
c+=1;
var fitb_answer=document.getElementById("fitb_ans").value;
if (fitb_answer=="balloon")
{
score+=1;
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML=correct;
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML=score;
}
else if (document.getElementById("fitb_ans").checked==false)
{
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML=incorrect;
}
}
// function for True/False question
function tfQ()
{
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("fitb_ques").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("answer_a").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("answer_b").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("answer_c").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="Counter is "+c;
document.getElementById("tf_ques").innerHTML="7. Put question 7 here.";
document.getElementById("tf_ques").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("T").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("F").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("answer_true").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("answer_false").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("T").innerHTML="True";
document.getElementById("F").innerHTML="False";
}
// function checks True/False question
function check_tfQ()
{
c+=1;
If (document.getElementById('answer_true').checked)
{
score+=1;
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML=correct;
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML=score;
}
/* else if (document.getElementById("answer_true").checked==false)
{
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML=incorrect;
} */ 
}
// function declaration for clearing the form
function clearform(form)
{
document.Questions.reset(form);
document.getElementById("reply_a").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("reply_b").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("testscore").innerHTML="";
}
// function declaration to disable all radio buttons after checking answers
function holdAnswers()
{
var obj=document.forms["Questions"]; 
            for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++) { 
                with (obj[i]) { 
                    if (type=='radio') { 
                        disabled=true; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
}
function releaseAnswers()
{
var obj=document.forms["Questions"]; 
            for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++) { 
                with (obj[i]) { 
                    if (type=='radio') { 
                        disabled=false; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
}
// function changes questions after each answer
function qlogger()
{
switch (c)
{
case 1:
Question1();
releaseAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=false;
break;
case 2:
Question2();
releaseAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=false;
break;
case 3:
Question3();
releaseAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=false;
break;
case 4:
Question4();
releaseAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=false;
break;
case 5:
Question5();
releaseAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=false;
break;
case 6:
fitbQ();
releaseAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=false;
break;
case 7:
tfQ();
releaseAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=false;
break;
case 8:
results(score,c);
break;
}
}
//function declaration to check all answers to questions and provide output
function checkAll(c)
{
switch (c)
{
case 1:
checkQ1();
break;
case 2:
checkQ2();
break;
case 3:
checkQ3();
break;
case 4:
checkQ4();
break;
case 5:
checkQ5();
break;
case 6:
check_fitbQ();
break;
case 7:
check_tfQ();
break;
case 8:
results();
}
holdAnswers();
document.getElementById("tally").disabled=true;
}
function results(score,c)
{
grade=Math.round((score/(c-1))*100);
document.getElementById("main_ques").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("answer_a").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("answer_b").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("answer_c").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("tally").style.visibility="hidden";
if (grade>=80)
{
document.getElementById("results1").innerHTML="Congratulations! <br/>"; 
document.getElementById("results2").innerHTML="You passed with a score of "+ grade+"%";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("results1").innerHTML="Sorry. <br>";
document.getElementById("results2").innerHTML="You failed with a score of "+grade+"%";
}
}
//-->
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="clearform(); qlogger()">
<div id="title">Module Title</div>
<div id="subtitle">Module Subtitle</div>
<div class="questions">
<form name="Questions">
<!-- Multiple choice question placeholder is here -->
<div id="main_ques">1. Please state your question here?</div>
<!-- Correct or Incorrect response -->
<div id="reply_a" class="response"></div>
<div id="reply_b" class="response2"></div>
<!-- Test score displays here -->
<div id="testscore" class="showscore"></div>
<!-- Test results displays here -->
<div id="results1" class="results1"></div>
<div id="results2" class="results2"></div>
<br>
<!-- Multiple choice radio buttons go here -->
<input type="radio" name="Q_ans" id="answer_a" class="answer_a" value="ans_a"/><br><div id="choice1" class="choice1"></div>
<input type="radio" name="Q_ans" id="answer_b" class="answer_b" value="ans_b"/><br><div id="choice2" class="choice2"></div>
<input type="radio" name="Q_ans" id="answer_c" class="answer_c" value="ans_c"/><br><div id="choice3" class="choice3"></div>
<!-- Put fill in the blank question here -->
<div id="fitb_ques" class="fitb_ques">6. Please state your fill in the <input name="fitb_ans" id="fitb_ans"> question here.</div>
<!-- Put True/False question here -->
<div id="tf_ques" class="tf_ques">7. Please state your T/F question here.</div>
<input type="radio" name="TF_ans" id="answer_true" class="true_btn" value="true_ans"/><br><div id="T" class="T">Put choice one here.</div>
<input type="radio" name="TF_ans" id="answer_false" class="false_btn" value="false_ans"/><br><div id="F" class="F">Put choice two here.</div> 
<div id="counter"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" name="tally" id="tally" value="score" onclick="checkAll(c)">
</form>
</div>
<div id="nextbutton">
<input type="image" src="pics/next_button.png" alt="Next Button" height="50" width="120" onclick="clearform();qlogger()">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On what line? Do you really expect us to read all that unindented code?

Comment: Formatting your code will make it one billion times easier for people to help...

Comment: In the future, please try to limit the code that you post to only that which is relevant. It's very hard to read through dozens (or hundreds) of lines of irrelevant code to find the important part(s). In this case, for instance, since the problem occurs when calling `check_tfQ()`, you could have posted only that function.

Answer (score 8):

You have an upper case "I" in `If (...`. Change it to lower case: `if (...`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: That's when an IDE comes in handy, huh? ;)

Comment: @DanMan - Nah. OP said the error was when calling `check_tfQ`, so I looked for the function name and there it was.

Comment: Thank you for catching the upper case If. I was sure it was something simple. Sorry about the code bloat:- \

Comment: @DarinFennell - If that solved the problem, how about accepting the answer? :)